# Mathematical induction to prove equipotent sets. Schröder–Bernstein theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, induction

as a proposed exercise, I am trying to prove the Schröder–Bernstein theorem using a different approach.
So first, based on the following definitions:
let $A, B$ be non-empty sets and functions $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$, such that $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one. Define recursively $\forall n\geq 1$:

$$
A_0 := A, B_0 := B, A_1 := g(B_0), B_1 := f(A_0), A_2 := g(B_1), B_2 := f(A_1), ...
$$
Basically,
$$
A_n := g(B_{n-1}), B_n := f(A_{n-1})
$$

I must (for the moment and in what I need help with) prove that:
$$
|A|=|A_0|=|B_1|=|A_2|=|B_3|=|A_4|=...
$$

I'm trying to prove this by induction. I have already done the (base) cases $|A_0|=|B_1|$ and $|B_1|=|A_2|$ by showing there is, in fact, a bijective function between them (by restricting the respective codomain and using the inverse functions of $f$ and $g$, respectively). However, I am having trouble proving the rest of the cases (I'm stuck with no ideas). I do not have a clear path in how to use induction for this.

What I have tried so far is something along the lines of:

Assume that the following is true for $k\geq 0$:

$|A_{2k}|=|B_{2k +1}|$

Then, prove that it holds for

$|A_{2(k+1)}|=|B_{2(k+1) +1}|$

Basically, using induction, but my issue is that I honestly do not know how to connect what I did (and how I did it) on the base cases with this. I believe I'm having trouble with how to use the idea of restricting the codomain each time (it is not clear to me). I know this speaks more about my lack of understanding of what I am doing, but I would appreciate any pointers on how to proceed or any ideas on how I can make it easier to follow or how to put it into words.

Also, English is not my first language so I'm sorry for any grammar mistakes.

Comment: The image of an injective function has the same cardinality as its domain. The function is a bijection between the domain and the image.

Comment: Also, the function $h:A\rightarrow A$ given by $h(x)=g(f(x))$ is injective. You have $A_{k+2}=h(A_k)$. So, with the previous comment, you get $|A_0|=|A_2|=|A_4|=|A_6|=...$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you

Comment: Not a comment on your question itself, but I am curious where you are going with this. You might want to consider $A = \{p \in \Bbb C\mid p^*p < 1\}$ and $B = \Bbb C$ with $f: A\to B : re^{i\theta} \mapsto re^{i(1+\theta/2)}$ (where $0\le \theta < 2\pi$) and $g : z \mapsto -z$. Then $$g\circ f : re^{i\theta} \mapsto re^{i(1 + \pi/2 + \theta/2)}$$ and $$f\circ g : re^{i\theta} \mapsto re^{i(1 + \pi/4 + \theta/2)}.$$ There is no dependable common set between or "limit set" that they converge to. Just knowing that you have two sequences of sets of constant size doesn't say much.